# How to attach CSS with HTML using sublime text in window 7?

Tags: css

I searched about this question but no one told me about it correctly so tell me the answer

Comment: Your question is not valid yet!

Answer (score 0):

IF this is a question then the answer should be this one :

1. Download & Install Sublime text editor
2. Open Sublime text editor
3. Create two files and open them

**1. index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**2. style.css**

```
/*
  This is your stylesheet
*/

body{
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #007bff;
}
```